# Dynamically adding a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to create a list(UITableView) with a customview(UITableViewCell) consisting three labels that takes user's data, lets say first name and lastname, department, when you click on add button(outside the list), a new user custom view is added to the list, where you can enter another user detail.
I know how to create a customView in a tableView
I know how to append to a tableView if its just a text, but what i want to append to the tableview is a customView on click of a button.

to add a text to a tableView, i did something like below.

```
datas.insert("new data", at: 0)
        jobTableView.beginUpdates()
        jobTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
        jobTableView.endUpdates()
```

How do i do it for customView?

Below is my tableview

**UITableviewClass**

```
public class MiddlePartCell: BaseCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

let tableCell = "tableCell"

lazy var jobTableView: UITableView = {
   let tv = UITableView()
    tv.backgroundColor = .brown
    tv.dataSource = self
    tv.delegate = self
    return tv
}()

lazy var addMoreButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "plus"), for: .normal)
    button.tintColor = .black
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleAddJob), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    return button
}()

@objc private func handleAddJob(){
    //what should i do here 
    //i need to insert the custom view to the top index
    jobTableView.beginUpdates()
    jobTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    jobTableView.endUpdates()
}

override func setupView() {
    super.setupView()
    backgroundColor = .green
    addSubview(jobTableView)
    addSubview(addMoreButton)

    jobTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: tableCell)

    _ = addMoreButton.anchor(nil, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: nil, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 10, bottomConstant: 10, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 50, heightConstant: 50)

    _ = jobTableView.anchor(topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: addMoreButton.topAnchor, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: frame.width, heightConstant: frame.height)
}

public func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: tableCell, for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = datas[indexPath.item]

    return cell
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return datas.count
  }
}
```

Comment: you have to insert into your data source array in your handleAddJob function as well.

Comment: @koropok how can add a new custom view into a table view

Comment: by custom view, do you mean a new UITableViewCell? I'm not sure if I can understand your question.

Comment: @koropok a UITableViewCell

Comment: You want to add a custom UITableViewCell with UITextField?

Comment: @koropok that's exactly what i want to do, i need be able to persist the data at some point also

Comment: You can subclass UITableViewCell for a custom cell with a UITextField, then have a variable to indicator if the user wants to add a new cell, then insert into your datasource array, then inside your cellForRowAt you check the indicator variable and use the custom cell with textField?

Comment: @koropok am sorry, its not clear, i really don't know what to do, with what you just said i think you understand the question

Comment: hold on, i'll show you an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have to subclass UITableViewCell for a UITableViewCell with UITextField. Of course you can add the UITextField inside cellForRowAt delegate function but I prefer to do it with a custom UITableViewCell.

```
class UITableViewCellWithTextField: UITableViewCell {

    var textField: UITextField!

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {

        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {

        let textField = UITextField(frame: self.contentView.frame)
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.textField)
    }
}
```

Next, you have to register this custom UITableViewCell into your UITableView. Add this to your existing UITableViewCell registration line of code.

```
jobTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: tableCell)
jobTableView.register(UITableViewCellWithTextField.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TextFieldCell")
```

The next step is to declare a variable to indicate that the user has initiated the add new job function.

```
public class MiddlePartCell: BaseCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var isHandlingAddJob = false

    ...
}
```

Then in your handleAddJob function

```
func handleAddJob(){

    self.isHandlingAddJob = true
    datas.insert("new data", at: 0)
    jobTableView.beginUpdates()
    jobTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    jobTableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Lastly is to let the UITableView know that the incoming new cell to handle adding of a new job, and should use the custom text field cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0 && self.isHandlingAddJob {

        // Handling new job cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextFieldCell", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCellWithTextField
        return cell
    }

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: tableCell, for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = datas[indexPath.item]
    return cell
}
```

P.S. Hope I'm understanding your question correctly lol.

To persist the data of the text field in the custom table view cell, you have to use the delegate pattern. Firstly, you have to either conform your custom table view cell or MiddlePartCell class to UITextFieldDelegate. I will be going for the latter.

```
class MiddlePartCell: BaseCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

    ...
}
```

Then in your cellForRowAt function, you set your custom cell's text field delegate to your MiddlePartCell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0 && self.isHandlingAddJob {

        // Handling new job cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextFieldCell", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCellWithTextField
        cell.returnKeyType = .Done
        cell.textField.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    ...
}
```

Lastly, use the UITextFieldDelegate function. When the use click done on the keyboard, your cell will be reloaded to be a normal UITableViewCell without UITextField.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    self.isHandlingAddJob = false
    self.datas.first! = textField.text!
    self.jobTableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    return true
}
```

Comment: Let me give it a try and get back to you

Comment: This works, however how can i track what is entered in each cell textField

Comment: I think i might have confused you a little, the customview has other views in it, not just input fields, i have buttons, and label also, i just shortened it for clarity hope its still on track?

Comment: yep you can just add ur buttons, labels into the custom uitableviewcell however you see fit.

Comment: Thanks, one more thing, i don't know if i should edit the question or create a new question(I am thinking it will be more complex to answer for other people and you might not see it), how can i make the customview expandable, when its collapse it shows a text, and when it expands it shows the views in the custom view, you can probably help me put it in a link and share it here, THanks.

Comment: I think it is best that you create a new question. I have only tried expandable UITableViewCells once and I'm using a third party framework due to time constraint, thus I believe I'm not the best person for this question. As a matter of fact, there are already quite a few SO questions regarding expandable cells already, just give it a search and I'm sure you can find your answer.